# How to perform data carving using FTK imager for a deleted file ?(i.e locating the runlist and accessing the cluster info)

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, recovery, data-recovery, computer-forensics

I want to carve the data of a deleted file manually by locating its run list and thus obtaining the cluster length and starting cluster for carving out the data from its Master File Table using FTK Imager, I did data carving for an image that is not deleted but I am not able to locate the run list incase of the deleted file using FTK imager. I followed the steps given here in the below website for locating the run list but not able to do so for a deleted file, please give me your suggestions.

Refer NTFS file recovery concept section from https://www.ntfs.com/recovery-toolkit.htm
https://issuu.com/parveskamal/docs/ftk_step_by_step

Also, I am hereby attaching the image of the MFT record of a deleted file for which I want to perform data carving
PSs:The highlighted part is athe data attribute section from where we could obtain the runlist(info about the cluster where the data is stored)

[image]